# Move objetct perpendicular to the viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view, constraints

The easiest way to move an object (G key) moves it parallel to the viewport.

BUT, is there any way to move it PERPENDICULAR to the viewport? That is, in depth but not just constrained to the XYZ axis/planes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the transform orientations to "view", then press G Z, move the mouse and confirm with left click.

If your view is orthographic you will not see any apparent movement but you can read the distance you're moving in the top left corner of the 3D window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh. Is what I asked for. The problem for me is that, for a lot of other purposes, I need to work with the global orientation. My idea is to replicate what I use to do with Cinema4D: when moving an object I could press a key (shift perhaps?) and move the object to the background/foreground in a very seamless way. The same accesibility that uses blender to do precise movements. This is useful for me because I like to work in stereoscopy (parallel mode), feeling the 3D space, and to be constrained to the axis is a pain. I've configured the "G" key to move freely in the XZ plane as is exp

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Transform Orientation to View, then  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will translate in  Screen space.. (Z being in and out of the screen).

Double-tapping the dimension (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) will revert the translation to Global space, whichever orientation you have selected.